# In R loop through one data frame to generate another data frame conditionally with one or more rows for each row in the first data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
set.seed(71)
dat <- data.table(region = rep(c('A','B'), each=10),
    place = rep(c('C','D'), 10),
    start = sample.int(5, 20, replace = TRUE),
    end = sample.int(10, 20, replace = TRUE),
    count = sample.int(50, 20, replace = TRUE),
    para1 = rnorm(20,3,1),
    para2 = rnorm(20,4,1))
```

I would like to loop through this data to conditionally generate another table with the following columns:
  region, place, start, end, count, count0
  with potentially more than one rows for each row in dat.
  in the new table, data for columns region, place, and start will be copied over from dat, and data for columns end, count, and count0 will be generated.

Here are the rules for iterating through each row of dat:

```
end = end +1
if (count=0) {
  count0=0
} else {
  count0=start*para1 + end*para2
}
if (count0>count) {
  count0=count
}
count = count -count0
```

I tried to use the combination of for loop, if statement, and mutate but could not get it right.

I expect to get a table like this after going through the first two rows of dat:

```
region  place   start   end       count         count0
     A      C       2     7  6.01673062    17.98326938
     A      C       2     8           0     6.01673062
     A      D       3     2  5.34392419     7.65607581
     A      D       3     3           0     5.34392419


the first two rows of dat I have are:
region  place   start   end count   para1         para2
     A      C       2     6    24   0.39412969  2.45643
     A      D       3     1    13   0.64372127  2.862456
```

Comment: I don't understand from your psuedocode how there are "potentially more than one rows for each row in dat". What determines if there is more than one row from a single row?

Comment: Something to note: if you are checking a boolean (T/F like in an if statement), you should use `==`, not `=`.

Comment: the function call count0=start*para1 + end*para2 generates a value and the value will be compared with the value in the count variable. if it is smaller than count, a new row will be generated and the new function value will be compared with the remainder of the count value. This process continues until the value of count becomes zero. So if the count value is big, it could be many rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Here's a lazy approach that should still be extremely fast, at the cost of temporarily making rows that we'll remove at the end. Rather than figure out how many copies to make of each row, I make a bunch of copies of every row, then apply fast vectorized calculations to get the updated `end`, `count`, and `count0` values, and remove the rows we don't need.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
output <-
  dat %>%
  mutate(orig_row = row_number()) %>%
  uncount(10) %>%   # I'm assuming here that 10 is enough columns
  group_by(orig_row) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(
    end = end + row,
    count0 = pmin(count, start * para1 + end * para2), # Edit #2
    count = count - cumsum(count0)
  ) %>%
  filter(lag(count, default = 0) >= 0) %>%
  mutate(count = pmax(0, count),
         count0 = if_else(count == 0, lag(count), count0))
output


# A tibble: 4 x 10
# Groups:   orig_row [2]
  region place start   end count para1 para2 orig_row   row count0
  <chr>  <chr> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <int> <int>  <dbl>
1 A      C         2     7  6.02 0.394  2.46        1     1  18.0 
2 A      C         2     8  0    0.394  2.46        1     2   6.02
3 A      D         3     2  5.34 0.644  2.86        2     1   7.66
4 A      D         3     3  0    0.644  2.86        2     2   5.34
```

---

Initial answer:

I imagine this is in the neighborhood.

Caveat: I didn't get the same sample data as you showed, nor do I understand how the specific numbers in your provided sample would generate the suggested output. For instance, from the first row of `dat` you show (different than I got), the first count0 should be `2*0.394 + 6*2.456 = 15.527`, no?

My approach here is to calculate `count0`, and then figure out how many of `count` fit into it, then make that many copies of the row, decrementing `count` by `count0` with each row.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
output <- dat %>%
  mutate(end = end + 1,
         orig_data = row_number(),
         count0 = if_else(count == 0, 0,
                          start*para1 + end*para2),
         copies = 1 + count %/% count0) %>%
  uncount(copies) %>%
  group_by(orig_data) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number() - 1,
         count = count - row * count0)
```

---

BTW, my `dat` initializes differently using `set.seed(71)`. Could you please confirm if your data initializes as provided in the OP? It will be easier to get aligned if we can start from the same place.

```
> head(dat)
   region place start end count    para1    para2
1:      A     C     2   7    19 3.400587 2.757140
2:      A     D     3   3    31 1.503740 6.089518
3:      A     C     2   8     2 2.561869 5.236298
4:      A     D     2   3    33 3.069835 3.770121
5:      A     C     2   2    21 2.989221 3.547926
6:      A     D     5   5    32 2.720636 5.379352
```

Comment: Yes, this is in the right direction but there are a couple of details missing. I am sure it is because my problem description is not clear enough.  The variable end needs to add 1 in each iteration. As a result, the computed count0 value also changes in each row.  Also, the total of count0 in multiple rows of the new table need to add up to count value of the row in the first table that they are based on.  Lastly, the count value in the new table decreases and must end with zero.

Comment: The first count0 should be 2*0.394 + 7*2.456 = 17.98326938. this is computed after adding 1 to end in each iteration.

Comment: Could you please verify that the example data you provided is what is generated immediately after running the initialization code? I've added the first rows of dat to my answer; it's different than yours and that makes it harder to understand where the differences lie.

Comment: My run results in different data even with the same seed.  Please use yours instead.  The key is that the variable end is different in each row of the new table (end=end+1) and count0 needs to be computed using the new end values. With each count0, it needs to be checked to make sure it does not exceed the remaining count value. if it does, it should take the value of count.  the value of count should reduce accordingly in each row until it reaches zero.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just use the two lines of data that I posted and not try to generate more data.

Comment: The code produces desired results for the most part, except when the first computed count0 is bigger than count, instead of taking on the value of count, it produces an NA.

Comment: A fix I can think of is to insert counts=count before count is changed, and add count0=ifelse(is.na(count0), counts, count0) at the end. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: I think the `count0 = pmin(count, start * para1 + end * para2), # Edit #2` line should fix this.

Comment: Yes, it does.  Jon, thank you so much for your kind help.